# Laravel How do the count for each user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

I want to retrieve in my result 3 fields the count of `walls`, `follow` and `exos` for each user.

The code below give me the same count for each field:

```
$profils = \DB::table('users')
->select(['users.*',\DB::raw('count(follow.user_id) as likeme'), \DB::raw('count(murs.user_id) as murme'), \DB::raw('count(exos.user_id) as exome')])
        ->leftjoin('murs', 'users.id', '=', 'murs.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('exos', 'users.id', '=', 'exos.user_id')             
        ->leftjoin('follow', 'users.id', '=', 'follow.user_id')
        ->groupby('users.id')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Comment: what's the problem in the above query?

Comment: The result is not correct, for example I must receive:
user1 count(follow.user_id) = 5
USER1 count(exos.user_id) = 8
USER1 count(walls.user_id) = 17

but with this request, I get a result of 10 of each count(), by against, if I am a single count() in my request I get the good result.

Comment: @nabil: do you have any table prefix? and can you also share your SQL query which is giving you the desired result.

Comment: @RaunakGupta table prefix, no! my SQL query : SELECT
Count(follow.user_id) AS likeme,
Count(murs.user_id) AS murme,
Count(exos.user_id) AS exome,
users.id,
users.name
from users
left join murs on(users.id = murs.profil_id)
left join exos on(users.id = follow.profil_id)
left join follow on(users.id = follow.profils_id)
GROUP BY
users.id  

also with this sql query I don't the result desired!?

Comment: add toSql() to your code ex : "$profils = \DB::table('users')->select()..........->paginate(15)->toSql() " it will give you raw query and then analyse what's the issue

Comment: I get this error : Method toSql‌​ does not exist!?

Comment: try by debuging through `DB::enableQueryLog();` and `dd(DB::getQueryLog())`; and see you are getting same SQL or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$profils = \DB::table('users')
->select(['users.*',\DB::raw('count(DISTINCT(follow.user_id)) as likeme'), \DB::raw('count(DISTINCT(murs.user_id)) as murme'), \DB::raw('count(DISTINCT(exos.user_id)) as exome')])
        ->leftjoin('murs', 'users.id', '=', 'murs.user_id')
        ->leftjoin('exos', 'users.id', '=', 'exos.user_id')             
        ->leftjoin('follow', 'users.id', '=', 'follow.user_id')
        ->groupby('users.id')
        ->paginate(15);
```

Let me know if this will not work for you.

Comment: I receive the number 1 for the three fields!?